# Generating a TreeMap of Frequencies for each Number in a List

Tags: java, list, treemap

I have a method which is meant to return a `TreeMap` with the *keys* being the numbers and the *values* being the frequencies of these numbers in the given array:

```
public TreeMap<Integer, Integer> getFrequencyCount(List<Integer> array) {
    Collections.sort(array);
    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> a = new TreeMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
        if (array.indexOf(array.get(i)) == 0 || array.get(i) != array.get(i - 1)){
            a.put(array.get(i), 1);
            
        } else if (array.get(i) == array.get(i - 1)) {
            int votes = a.get(array.get(i));
            a.put(array.get(i), votes + 1);
        }   
    }
    return a;
}
```

Every value is correct **except for** the **first value** of the map, which is always `1`. I can't figure out why it's happens.

Comment: What value do you expect for what input and what was the actual output?

Comment: _"it returns a map with the keys being the numbers and the values being how many times the number appears in the array"_ - no it does not.

Answer (score 0):

> the first value of the map, which is always `1`

That happens because when an element is equal to the first element in the sorted list - `indexOf() == 0` in the snippet below, the value associated with it will always be `1`. The second part of this condition is also fishy.

```
if (array.indexOf(array.get(i)) == 0 || array.get(i) != array.get(i - 1)) {
   a.put(array.get(i), 1);
}
```

I guess instead the condition should be `if (!a.containsKey(array.get(i)))`

There's a few more issues with your code:

- Don't compare objects using `==` or `!=` unless you don't need to make sure that two references point to the same object. Instances of `Integer` are objects. To compare values of the objects, use `equals()` method.
- Don't confuse *array* and `ArrayList` (and avoid using confusing names). Array is the simplest data container built-in into the language, it has **no** behavior. On the other hand, `ArrayList` is a `Collection`, backed by an array (and there are some others apart from `ArrayList`), which offers lots of useful methods.
- Write your code against interfaces. We have a contract `NavigableMap`, use it as a type when you need `TreeMap`.
- By sorting the list data, you're not getting a performance advantage. If your goal was to try implementing this task by iterating over the sorted list - that's fine. But mind that method `get()` and `put()` have a time complexity of **O(n)** for `TreeMap`. If you want to go this route (meaning to sort data in the list) it would be chipper to store the results into `LinkedHashMap` and then dump it into `TreeMap` (method `putAll()` is capable of taking advantage of the previously sorted data of the map passed into it).

Here's an alternative way of implementing this task using Java 8 method [`merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)):

```
public NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> getFrequencyCount(List<Integer> list) {

    Map<Integer, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();

    for (Integer next: list) {
        frequencies.merge(next, 1, Integer::sum);
    }

    return new TreeMap<>(frequencies);
}
```

And if you're comfortable with streams, you can make use of one of the flavors of [`Collectors.toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)):

```
public NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> getFrequencyCount(List<Integer> list) {

    return list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Function.identity(),
            i -> 1,
            Integer::sum,
            TreeMap::new
        ));
}
```